# Which object should I use in XCode IB?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm messing around with Xcode and Interface Builder. I want to make a timer or clock type app. What type of object should the numbers be? Just a 'Label'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 'Label' (which is a modified `NSTextField`), or you could use an non-editable `NSTextField` or even a `NSView` with a custom drawing method.

If you're still learning, I suggest you use a Label and go from there.

When linking to your `AppDelegate` (or whatever object you're using), remember to create an `IBOutlet` on your property declaration so you can link your label, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *clockLabel;
```

And setup the clock value using the `setStringValue:` method:

```
[self.clockLabel setStringValue:myString];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the numbers, then **UILabel** will be just fine.

And, if you want some nice looks then i would recommend some nice graphics images for the numbers.

Comment: I believe he's coding for OSX, not iOS. `UILabel` is only for the iOS platform. On OSX, the label is a `NSTextField` class.